# $http request in angular config - Is it possible?

Tags: angularjs, express, angular-ui-router

I am trying to make an $http call inside my publicApp.config in order to retrieve an array of available routes to match with the $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.

Right now, I am hard-coding them to be `pageUrls = ['about','contact','another-page'];`

But I have an url in my express API which returns an array of available URLS. The api URL is `"/page-urls"`

Would it be possible to make an `$http.get('/page-urls')` request inside the config? I know $http is available inside `run()`, but I need the list of available URLs BEFORE routing via the $stateProvider.

```
(function() {
    'use strict'

    var pageUrls = [];

    var publicApp = angular.module('publicApp', ['ui.router'])

    publicApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$urlMatcherFactoryProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $urlMatcherFactoryProvider) {

        pageUrls = ['about','contact','another-page'];  

        var urls = pageUrls.join('|');
        var urlMatcher = $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.compile("/{source:(?:" + urls + ")}");


        $stateProvider      
            .state('/', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: "views/home/home.view.html",
                controller: "homeCtrl"
            })
            .state('urls', {
                    url: urlMatcher,
                    templateUrl: "views/pages/page.view.html",
                    controller: "pageCtrl"
                });

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');


    }]);



})();
```

Comment: To do this with ajax you would need to make request outside of angular app , manually bootstrap app within the ajax success instead of using `ng-app` and pass data in from global variable. Then it would be available when config runs

Comment: There is an alternative [router-extras](https://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/home) that lets you define router states after config

Comment: Could i just add a js file with the array of urls before my angular app? Is that a safe option?

Comment: I was going to suggest that also. Would be quickest to set up and would let you continue with `ng-app`

Comment: Ok cool, I am dynamically adding pages via a backend admin app. I guess I can update the "cached" js file of urls via node each time I add / edit / remove a page.

Comment: There might be other projects I'm not aware of that also facilitate this. Worth doing more searching to find out

Comment: Or you could actually still use $http in config (although it's a bit hacky).

Comment: I guess with an included array, I save myself an extra api call. Plus I can update the array using express in my api so i guess it would work

Comment: Trying not to hack angular so much as this is my first big project

Comment: @dfsq curious how you would prevent initial route request inside config when it hasn't been defined yet. Obviously can set up default in advance. I guess could track within route error handler and then redirect once they are defined. Seems like a pain but interested in concept

Comment: @charlietfl Not sure what initial request you are talking about. I mean it is possible to get $http instance and load routes array before $routeProvider configuration.

Comment: @dfsq right but my thinking is would need some route basics defined  before `$http` completes. Just not seeing how app would manage the initial bootsrapping of the url without a route configured for it .. or have to use `$state.reload()` or something once $http did complete inside config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a provider which gets `$stateProvider` as an injectable. The provider will create a service that does the http request then registers the routes. Inject the service in a run block and initiate route registration.

Something like this:

```
var publicApp = angular.module('publicApp', ['ui.router'])

publicApp.provider('routes', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $urlMatcherFactoryProvider){
    function registerRoutes(listOfUrls){
        // register routes with $stateProvider
        // angular.forEach(listOfUrls, function(url){
        //     $stateProvider.state...
        // });
    }

    this.$get = function($http){
        return {
            initialize: function(){
                return $http.get('/page-urls').then(function(response){
                    registerRoutes(response.data);
                });
            }
        };
    };
});

publicApp.run(function(routes){
    routes.initialize();
});
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but I get an error saying
 "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined"

Comment: Here is the link to my question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39464624/call-to-a-function-within-get-of-provider-modules-causes-typeerror