# Call to a function within $get of Provider modules causes TypeError

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my provider.

```
App.provider('cloudinaryDetails', function(CloudinaryProvider){

function setCloudinaryDetails(cloudinaryDetails){
    CloudinaryProvider.configure({
        cloud_name: cloudinaryDetails.cloud_name,
        api_key: cloudinaryDetails.api_key
    });
}

this.$get = function($http){
    return {
            initialize: function(){
            return $http.get('path/to/api').then(function(response){
                setCloudinaryDetails(response.data);
            });
        }
    };
};
```

});

I am calling the initialize function in config module

```
App.config(function(cloudinaryDetailsProvider){
cloudinaryDetailsProvider.initialize();

});
```

Console Error:

[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module App due to:
TypeError: cloudinaryDetailsProvider.initialize is not a function

Comment: You can't call method of `$get`(constructor) inside a config function..

Comment: @PankajParkar I need to set Cloudinary details (cloudName , api_key) in the config, and i want to get those details from server. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

### Cause:

You are injecting the `cloudinaryDetailsProvider` "provider" but `initialize` is not defined on the provider, it is defined on the instance.

### Suggested Fix:

To get a reference to the `cloudinaryDetails` "instance", create a run block and inject the instance instead of the provider.

```
App.run(function(cloudinaryDetails){
  cloudinaryDetails.initialize();
});
```

See [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe) for an explanation on how providers work